# Calling macro from within generated function in Julia

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming, auto-generate

I have been messing around with generated functions in Julia, and have come to a weird problem I do not understand fully: My final goal would involve calling a macro (more specifically `@tullio`) from within a generated function (to perform some tensor contractions that depend on the input tensors). But I have been having problems, which I narrowed down to calling the macro from within the generated function.

To illustrate the problem, let's consider a very simple example that also fails:

```
macro my_add(a,b) 
    return :($a + $b)
end

function add_one_expr(x::T) where T
    y = one(T)
    return :( @my_add($x,$y) )
end

@generated function add_one_gen(x::T) where T
    y = one(T)
    return :( @my_add($x,$y) )
end
```

With these declarations, I find that `eval(add_one_expr(2.0))` works just as expected and returns and expression

```
:(@my_add 2.0 1.0)
```

which correctly evaluates to `3.0`.

However evaluating `add_one_gen(2.0)` returns the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching +(::Type{Float64}, ::Float64)
```

Doing some research, I have found that `@generated` actually produces two codes, and in one only the types of the variables can be used. I think this is what is happening here, but I do not understand what is happening at all. It must be some weird interaction between macros and generated functions.

Can someone explain and/or propose a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it helpful to think of generated functions as having two components: the *body* and any *generated code* (the stuff inside a `quote..end`). The body is evaluated at compile time, and doesn't "know" the values, only the types. So for a generated function taking `x::T` as an argument, any references to `x` in the body will actually point to the type `T`. This can be very confusing. To make things clearer, I recommend the body *only* refer to types, never to values.

Here's a little example:

```
julia> @generated function show_val_and_type(x::T) where {T}
           quote
               println("x is ", x)
               println("\$x is ", $x)
               println("T is ", T)
               println("\$T is ", $T)
           end
       end
show_val_and_type

julia> show_val_and_type(3)
x is 3
$x is Int64
T is Int64
$T is Int64
```

The interpolated `$x` means "take the `x` from the body (which refers to `T`) and splice it in.

If you follow the approach of never referring to values in the body, you can test generated functions by removing the `@generated`, like this:

```
julia> function add_one_gen(x::T) where T
           y = one(T)
           quote
               @my_add(x,$y)
           end
       end
add_one_gen

julia> add_one_gen(3)
quote
    #= REPL[42]:4 =#
    #= REPL[42]:4 =# @my_add x 1
end
```

That looks reasonable, but when we test it we get

```
julia> add_one_gen(3)
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./REPL[48]:4 [inlined]
 [2] add_one_gen(x::Int64)
   @ Main ./REPL[48]:1
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[49]:1
```

So let's see what the macro gives us

```
julia> @macroexpand @my_add x 1
:(Main.x + 1)
```

It's pointing to `Main.x`, which doesn't exist. The macro is being too eager, and we need to delay its evaluation. The standard way to do this is with `esc`. So finally, this works:

```
julia> macro my_add(a,b) 
           return :($(esc(a)) + $(esc(b)))
       end
@my_add

julia> @generated function add_one_gen(x::T) where T
           y = one(T)
           quote
               @my_add(x,$y)
           end
       end
add_one_gen

julia> add_one_gen(3)
4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think I understand now. However, I do have a further question: In my case (the real-world one) I do not have control over the macro. Is there a way to escape the variables from within the generated function? If not, do I understand this is a bug in the library responsible of the macro and open an issue to address it? Thank you again!